# Python script works in IDLE, but receives an error when running through console. [ERROR CODE] Can only normalize non-empty string names. Unexpected ''

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard-events, pyautogui

```
import time
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



welcome = "Welcome to the manual multi script (This script is still in developement please be patient.)"
print (welcome.upper())
help = "\nIf you need anyhelp please contact Frame on discord. \n"
print (help.upper())



print('You are about to bind your coords to [ANTI-FREEZE]: \n')
print('Please press [SPACE] to continue\n ')

while True:
    if  keyboard.is_pressed('SPACE'):
        print('Press ENTER on the [ANTI-FREEZE] power to get its location')
        time.sleep(1)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ENTER'):
        x,y = pyautogui.position()
        print("\nYour current X pos: " + str(x) + "," + "\nYour current Y pos: " + str(y))
        antifX1 = x
        antifY1 = y
        x = antifX1
        y = antifY1
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\n[ANTIFREEZE]Your current X and Y coord is: " + '[ ' + str(x) + ' , ' + str(y) + ' ] \n')
        break
    if keyboard.is_pressed('N'):
        print('\nNo Problem! Next Question... ')
        break



print('You are about to bind your coords to [PORTAL]: \n')
print('Please press [SPACE] to continue\n ')

while True:   
    if keyboard.is_pressed('SPACE'):
            print('Press ENTER on the PORTAL power to get its location')
            time.sleep(1)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ENTER'):
            x,y = pyautogui.position()
            print("\nYour current X pos: " + str(x) + "," + "\nYour current Y pos: " + str(y))
            portalfX1 = x
            portalfY1 = y
            x = portalfX1
            y = portalfY1
            time.sleep(1)
            print("\n[PORTAL]Your current X and Y coord is: " + '[ ' + str(x) + ' , ' + str(y) + ' ] \n')
            break
    if keyboard.is_pressed('N'):
            print('\nNo Problem! Next Question... ')
            break

print('You are about to bind your coords to [FREEZE]: \n')
print('Please press [SPACE] to continue\n ')

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('SPACE'):
            print('Press ENTER on the antifreeze power to get its location')
            time.sleep(1)
    if keyboard.is_pressed('ENTER'):
            x,y = pyautogui.position()
            print("\nYour current X pos: " + str(x) + "," + "\nYour current Y pos: " + str(y))
            freezefX1 = x
            freezefY1 = y
            x = freezefX1
            y = freezefY1
            time.sleep(1)
            print("\n[FREEZE]Your current X and Y coord is: " + '[ ' + str(x) + ' , ' + str(y) + ' ] \n')
            break
    if keyboard.is_pressed('N'):
        print('\nNo Problem! Next Question... ')
        break

notice = ('[NOTICE] an input delay on 1 means 1 drop per second\n')
print(notice.upper())
time.sleep(1)
while True:
    print('Drop Delay [MAKE SURE YOU INSERT ANSWER ON THIS LINE]: ')
    Apause = input()
    print('[Script Complete!]')
    Apause = pyautogui.PAUSE
    break
a = input('\nPlease enter keybind[ANTIFREEZE]: \n')
b = input('Please enter keybind[PORTAL]: \n')
c = input('Please enter keybind[FREEZE]: \n')
while True:
        pos = pyautogui.position()
        afreezePOS = pyautogui.position(antifX1, antifY1)
        portalPOS = pyautogui.position(portalfX1, portalfY1)
        freezePOS = pyautogui.position(freezefX1, freezefY1)
        if keyboard.is_pressed(a):
            pyautogui.click(afreezePOS)
            Apause
            pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
            Apause
            pyautogui.moveTo(pos)
            Apause
            pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
            Apause
            print('[ANTI] was pressed. \n')
        if keyboard.is_pressed(b):
            pyautogui.click(portalPOS)
            pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
            Apause
            pyautogui.moveTo(pos)
            Apause
            pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
            Apause
            print('[PORTAL] was pressed. \n')
        if keyboard.is_pressed(c):
            pyautogui.click(freezePOS)
            Apause
            pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
            Apause
            pyautogui.moveTo(pos)
            Apause
            pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
            Apause
            print('[FREEZE] was pressed. \n')
```

When I run this code inside the python IDLE program, it works fine. I've tried everything and hope seems to be lost. Is there any other way for users to input their own key bind, like what I'm trying to do here? If there is any other alternative, I would gladly go to that. When I run through the console, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ovosc\Desktop\Multiking\Realmulti.py", line 99, in <module>
    if keyboard.is_pressed(a):
  File "C:\Users\ovosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 417, in is_pressed
    steps = parse_hotkey(hotkey)
  File "C:\Users\ovosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 358, in parse_hotkey
    steps.append(tuple(key_to_scan_codes(key) for key in keys))
  File "C:\Users\ovosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 358, in <genexpr>
    steps.append(tuple(key_to_scan_codes(key) for key in keys))
  File "C:\Users\ovosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 309, in key_to_scan_codes
    normalized = normalize_name(key)
  File "C:\Users\ovosc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keyboard\_canonical_names.py", line 1239, in normalize_name
    raise ValueError('Can only normalize non-empty string names. Unexpected '+ repr(name))
ValueError: Can only normalize non-empty string names. Unexpected ''
```

I'm completely lost and don't know how to fix this. Does anyone have a clue of what the problem even means?

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that you use `keybaord.is_pressed(a)` while **a** is a variable for an **input**.

```
#if keyboard.is_pressed(a):
if keyboard.is_pressed('a'): #it should be like this
            pyautogui.click(afreezePOS)
            Apause
            pyautogui.mouseDown(button='left')
            Apause
            pyautogui.moveTo(pos)
            Apause
            pyautogui.mouseUp(button='left')
            Apause
```

you should do the same for **b** and **c**